# Drop Down List in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve a value from a drop down list in MVC, I am able to bind the drop down list from a table but unable to save the id of the drop down value selected back to the database.

```
//The following is a snippet of my Create.aspx
<%= Html.dropdownlist("departments", "Select One")%>

//The following is a snippet of my HomeController.cs
public ActionResult Create()
{
    this.ViewData["departments"] = new SelectList(_service.ListDepartments(), "departmentID", "name");
    return View("Create");
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(int? deptID, [Bind(Exclude = "educationID")] tblEDA empToCreate)
{
    if (_service.CreateEmp(deptID, empToCreate))
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    return View("Create");
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `deptID` argument name to `departments`.

Arguments in MVC are matched to post/route data. Because you are creating a DropDownList with the name "departments", that is the name of the form element. When the data is submitted, there is no data named `deptID`, only `departments`.

I'd also make `deptID` an `int` (as apposed to `int?`) unless it's actually optional.